# WSO2 Greg Weblogic Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Can WSO2 GREG 4.6 be deployed on Weblogic Server?
I found old documentation about using ant to createWAR but that is no longer valid.

Can anyone point me to updated documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported later versions of carbon 4.0.0.  GREG 4.6.0 using carbon 4.x.x version, so it can not be deployed in weblogic.